# Can't assign a value to int which inside the class

Tags: c++, stack

I set the veriable but when i call it it's coming with different veriable.
It's working fine without for loop.But when i add the for loop the problem show's up.

```
#define Size 20

class Stack{
private:
    int stack[Size];
    int top;
public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    void info();

};

Stack::Stack(){
    cout<<"The stack is beign created"<<endl;
    cout<<"//////////////////////////"<<endl;
    top = -1; // The problem is here <<
    cout<<top<<endl;
    for(int i = 0;i <= Size;i++){
      stack[i] = 0;
    };
    cout<<top<<endl;
};

void Stack::info(){
cout<<top<<endl;
}
```

**My expectet output is :**

```
The stack is beign created 
//////////////////////////  
-1   
-1  
-1 
//////////////////////////
The stack is beign destroyed
```

**Current code's output is :**

```
The stack is beign created 
//////////////////////////  
-1 
0  
0
//////////////////////////
The stack is beign destroyed
```

Comment: You're overrunning `stack`. `Size` is `20`, and you are writing 21 elements.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you

Comment: One more problem - your code gave no 'stack overrun' error message or perhaps log entry.

Comment: Warning: `#define Size 20` carries some risk. Size is a fairly common word and the `Size` macro will quietly replace all appearances of it with 20 before the program is compiled, resulting in some really weird compiler errors if you reuse `Size`. Prefer to use `constexpr int Size = 20;` instead.

Comment: Please don't put "Solved" in the titles of questions. If an answer solves your issue, simply mark that answer as accepted.

Comment: I can only mark it after 15 min.While waiting i wrote it to title to dont disturb people with solved problem. @NikosC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overrunning `stack`. `Size` is `20`, and you are writing 21 elements.

Your `for` loop condition should be `i < Size`, not `i <= Size`.